# mono c# get application path

Tags: c#, mono

I am looking to get the directory of my application it seems to be different from regular c#?

As in `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)` is not working.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One correct and cross-platform solution would be

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

Note that both `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` (more exactly, the directory thereof) are semantically wrong even though they are often - but not always - the same directory:

- The *current directory* is the "working directory" and can be changed at any point in time, like the "cd" command does in a shell.
- The *executing assembly* is the assembly that contains the code which is currently running, and may or may not be in the same directory as the actual application. For instance if your application is "A.exe" which has a dependency "B.dll", and some code in B.dll calls `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`, it would result in "/path/to/B.dll".

Answer (score 1):

Try `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Comment: Assembly is not giving me anything, what should i be including to give me access to assembly?