# Get current folder path

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, path

I want to create a program that converts files. I would like the user to be able to place the executable file in any directory, and when executing that program (double-clicking on the .exe) I want the program to process **all the files within the current folder where the exe file exists**. How can the program determine the path in which it is currently executing?

I tried `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` but that seems to be the wrong way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 483, accepted):

You should **not** use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` in your case, as the current directory may differ from the execution folder, especially when you execute the program through a shortcut.

It's better to use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);` for your purpose. This returns the pathname where the currently executing assembly resides.

While my suggested approach allows you to differentiate between the executing assembly, the entry assembly or any other loaded assembly, as *Soner Gönül* said in his answer,

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

may also be sufficient. This would be equal to

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: GetEntryAssembly() and GetExecutingAssembly() has an interesting difference. For details refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18562036/30289

Comment: As I said: This returns the pathname where the *currently executing assembly* resides. The difference between `GetEntryAssembly` and `GetExecutingAssembly` doesn't come as much of a surprise, is also obvious by the function name. If they did the same, why should there be two functions? :-)

Comment: +1 Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() helped me in case of running application via clickonce

Comment: This is in System.Reflection, so `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` is the complete -- if you're testing from Immediate Window

Comment: I would also consider `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).Location)`. This allows getting the directory for any class desired. Just replace `MyClass` with a class contained in the assembly you are looking for. Then it will not matter whether it is the entry or executing assembly.

Answer (score 247):

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

This will give you running directory of your application. This even works for web applications. Afterwards you can reach your file.

Comment: This is the most accurate property to use for this purpose. The CurrentDomain's BaseDirectory will always point to the correct location even if the AppDomain is dynamically created to look the assemblies from a different location.

Comment: Perfect. This works independently for any application, especially when using Streamreader, which can read different absolute path's depending on the application type.

Answer (score 70):

I created a simple console application with the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
Console.WriteLine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory);
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

I copied the resulting executable to `C:\temp2`. I then placed a shortcut to that executable in `C:\temp3`, and ran it (once from the exe itself, and once from the shortcut). It gave the following outputs both times:

```
C:\temp2
C:\temp2\
C:\temp2
C:\temp2
C:\temp2
```

While I'm sure there must be *some* cockamamie reason to explain why there are **five different methods** that do virtually the exact same thing, I certainly don't know what it is. Nevertheless, it would appear that under most circumstances, you are free to choose whichever one you fancy.

**UPDATE:**
I modified the Shortcut properties, changing the "Start In:" field to `C:\temp3`. This resulted in the following output:

```
C:\temp2
C:\temp2\
C:\temp3
C:\temp3
C:\temp3
```

...which demonstrates at least *some* of the distinctions between the different methods.

Comment: An important note. The working directory is not always going to be the same as the installed directory.

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

[`System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory` can be changed in a number of ways... (shotrtcut settings, etc)

Answer (score 27):

Use this,

```
var currentDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

You can use this as well.

```
var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Answer (score 23):

```
string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

From [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)

> Returns the directory information for the specified path string.

From [`Application.ExecutablePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx)

> Gets the path for the executable file that started the application,
>   including the executable name.

Answer (score 18):

for **.NET CORE** use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory`

(as a replacement for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`)

Answer (score 8):

1.

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

2.

```
Thread.GetDomain().BaseDirectory
```

3.

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory` can be changed in a number of ways... (shotrtcut settings, etc)

Answer (score 2):

This block of code makes a path of your app directory in string type

```
string path="";
path=System.AppContext.BaseDirectory;
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

This works best for me, especially when using dotnet core single file publish.
`Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)`.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want the path of the project folder you also can do this:**

```
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(".");
       //OR 
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("../../../");

        Console.WriteLine(di.FullName);
```

**Result:**
D:\Dev\C#\ProjectFolder\ProjectFolder\

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Application.StartupPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx) for the best result imo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exe path you can use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);`