# How to get current working directory path c#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a cursor file in project. I have given the absolute path in code i.e

```
F:/r.cur
```

the problem is this is hard-coded path And i Want relative path so that if i move my solution to another system the code should not effect.

please suggest how to set relative path

```
//current code i am using 
 p.Cursor = new Cursor("F:/r.cur");
```

Comment: put it in the resource folder, and reference it as Properties.Reources.xxx

Comment: Have you tried to pack r.cur into your project directory?

Comment: @David yes i Have tried this by putting the r.cur file in recourse folder but its not showing it in code. its only showing .jpg type of files

Comment: @hbsrud If i try to pack r.cur in same project directory still i need to give absolute path. This might seems okay. but still it might have dependency if I make setup of the project and send it to another user

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni01, did you right click the resource file and put the action as "embedded resource", rather than "none" or "compile"?

Comment: @ David, This new thing i have learnt. but still it is not showing me ..;) suggest any other way

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni01 You should try Vignesh Kumars approach, put that ``r.cur`` in your project folder and then do ``p.Cursor = new Cursor(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "/r.cur");``

Comment: @hbsrud its also giving me C:\....\myProjectName\bin\Release Folder. and i want to put my cursor file to C:\....\myProjectName\Cursor\r.cur

Comment: In that case try ``p.Cursor = new Cursor(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "/Cursor/r.cur");``, but you have to change the Properties of r.cur, so it gets copied.

Comment: @hbsrud if i do this then new path will be: C:/..../MyProj/bin/Release/Cursor/r.cur ; but i want C:/..../MyProj/Cursor/r.cur;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current folder path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use static `Directory` class - however current directory is distinct from the original directory, which is the one from which the process was started.

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

So you can use the following to get the directory path of the application executable:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Comment: The above code dosen't work in WPF as as it not have System.Windows.Forms namespace.  Use the following instead System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)

Answer (score 4):

use     [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns path for the executable file that started the application.

```
        string pathCur = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\..\r.cur");
        Cursor = new Cursor(pathCur);
```

Comment: Its returning the C:\Users\yogeshkmrsoni\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProjectName\bin\Release  ; but i want to copy cursor file to C:\Users\yogeshkmrsoni\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProjectName\r.cur, can u suggest any other way

Comment: just to note: this is only for WinForms

Answer (score 4):

You can also get by
 `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`
but it shows bin and debug folder also, if you don't want these folder so you can use that code :

```
string page = "E:\abccom\Cat\Mouse.aspx"

string name = Path.GetFileName(page );
string nameKey = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(page );
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(page );

Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}",
page, name, nameKey, directory);
```

> Output:
>   GetFileName:                                        Mouse.aspx
>   GetFileNameWithoutExtension:           Mouse 
>   GetDirectoryName:                              E:\abccom\Cat

**Happy Coding :)**

Answer (score 3):

How about : `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

See more at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

Super super late to the party.

But depends on what you mean - if you're after the directory onto which your app code is finally deployed (on your test machine for example), then this works for a regular console app:

```
//gives something like D:\source\repos\Repo\src\AppName\bin\Debug\net6.0\Appame.dll
var assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location; 

//gives something like D:\source\repos\Repo\src\AppName\bin\Debug\net6.0
var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);

//gives something like D:\source\repos\Repo\src\AppName
var appRootFolder = currentDirectory.Split("\\bin")[0];

Console.WriteLine($"The root of the application is here: {appRootFolder}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current working directory by using `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. it will return your current executable path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Application.StartupPath should give you application path from where your application is running. I would create a directory structure under application folder. e.g If "C:\Program Files\MyApp" is my application folder, then I would create a folder named cursors under it (C:\Program Files\MyApp\Cursors") and put all cursors within this folder.

Answer (score 0):

`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)` at startup will give you the full path.

After that, if you * *really want to find something **during development** (as your comments in other answers point)* *, first find the path using `FileInfo(thestringwithfilenamepath).Directory.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Super late to this party, but this works for me when I'm in unit tests.

```
var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

If you need the root of the project, and not the bin directory then this:

```
var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var basePath = currentDirectory.Split(new string[] { "\\bin" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

It'll be different if you're on a website.

Answer (score 0):

For .net 6 and .net 7 I use:

```cs
var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"someFile.txt");
```