# c# - GetFiles() in DirectoryInfo class on phone device

Tags: c#, android, getfiles, directoryinfo

I am trying to get a list of files from my samsung phone when plugged in via usb on the computer. the code below return file not found exception due to part of path not found. However, the source path can be found on the file explorer.

```
string source = @"SAMSUNG\Phone";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(source);

dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Example of how the cellphone device display look similar to this:

[Example: screenshot of file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLxxd.jpg)

The error message listed my project name path\SAMSUNG\phone, which is weird. I tried this with regular USB thumbdrive that have an actual drive name and it works. Any advice help. Thank you!

Comment: Which protocol is your Android using? https://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/

Comment: My cellphone devices use MTP – Media Device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage files on an MTP Portable Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512737/how-to-manage-files-on-an-mtp-portable-device)

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate question, because there's another question with an answer that points to https://cgeers.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/wpd-transferring-content/ basically you're going to have to treat an MTP device completely differently to the regular file system.  It's possible and that link will give you what you need.  The other question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512737/how-to-manage-files-on-an-mtp-portable-device

Answer (score 0):

If you just put `SAMSUNG\Phone` it is treated as a relative path (relative to the [current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726088/how-to-get-current-working-directory-path-c) for your application). If you meant to access a [UNC share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482825/find-unc-path-of-a-network-drive/21497099), use `\\SAMSUNG\Phone`.

Comment: This still give me an error and I checked with Directory.Exists( returns not found). I also try @"This computer\SAMSUNG\Phone" and that doesn't work. I have the same error.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the Explorer view that shows the device is there in your filesystem?

Comment: i added screenshot on my question above. thank you in advance.