# Multiple Consoles in a Single Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

I have created a C# Project which has multiple console applications in it. Now my question is: **Is it possible to display multiple consoles when I run one application?** if yes, how?

Lets say, I have a Test Application, which is the main application. I have another two Console applications say, `ABC` and `XYZ`. Now, when i run the Test Application, the console of both applications ABC and XYZ should appear.

I have written the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("\n\t Calling EXE...");
Process myProcess = new Process();
string Exepath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\exe\\ABCApplication.exe";
try
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Exepath;
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    myProcess.Start();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    CreateLogFile();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean for debugging purposes? Or when running it normally?

Comment: Running it normally.

Comment: Please note that `GetCurrentDirectory` may not work as you expect it to work! See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path/15653938#15653938

Comment: Kindly check the question, I have written the code I used.

Comment: @Thorsten No, GetCurrentDirectory is working fine.

Comment: @harsh It may be working now, but you may get in trouble later. Just believe me. It does not solve your current problem, but you *will* run into trouble later on.

Comment: @Thorsten I am sorry! You are right. It does run into trouble, because the current directory differs from the execution folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a quick example of what can be done... obviously, adjust paths to your liking and there are a few other ways:

**Preview:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
using (var process1 = new Process())
{
    process1.StartInfo.FileName = @"..\..\..\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe";
    process1.Start();
}

using (var process2 = new Process())
{
    process2.StartInfo.FileName = @"..\..\..\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe";
    process2.Start();
}

Console.WriteLine("MainApp");
Console.ReadKey();
```

This was a quick setup and many things can be and should be adjusted (exception handling, etc., etc., etc.).  It should get you started, though.

Comment: @B.K. wow, what program did you use to create that video clip?

Comment: @Luther There are many screen capturing apps that create gifs.  I use LICEcap (http://www.cockos.com/licecap/), Screen To Gif (https://screentogif.codeplex.com/) and Gyazo (https://gyazo.com/).  Each has pros and cons.

Comment: I believe you can open any executable this way. I mistakenly copied the wrong path and it opened a console and a WindowsForms App. This was more than useful. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can start another process using the Process.Start() call. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) for examples

Comment: I tried to use the option you suggested, but its not working.

Comment: @Harsh: Then post some code so we can see why it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean, I want the console of both applications ABC and XYZ to appear, when I run the Test Application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

`ProcessStartInfo` allows you to capture console output.

You're probably looking for this: [Redirect standard output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Note you should also redirect standard error.