# VS 2022 How to run console for each project?

Tags: console, visual-studio-2022

I try to config my project to run two consoles - one for Angular front-end app project and the other for the asp .net core back-end project. But It doesn't work: Npm console starts, when the asp .net core console does not.

**Solution settings:**

[image]

Only the console does not appear and it seems to build the project (asp .net core) properly.
Any ideas how to set this?

Comment: Is your angular project hosted through ASP.Net or a standalone project?

Comment: As you have multiple startup projects, the server will start running and the browser will open simultaneously. If you try to run the front-end try (while the server is running) open a simultaneous command line outside of visual studio and run it. Hopefully it will run as expected.

Comment: EDIT: I made a mistake. In fact seckond project doesn't build at all. But, when i run them separately. Evrything is good.

Comment: @gunr2171 hosted by ASP.Net

Comment: Here I attach a reference to the PluralSight troubleshooting guide of the module "C# Interfaces" Troubleshooting Guide which may help you! https://github.com/jeremybytes/csharp-interfaces-resources/blob/main/TroubleShooting.md#issue-2

Comment: This is just a starting template. I do evrything like on this documentary page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022#troubleshooting, but I can't just get 2 consoles

Comment: OK: Now I created brand new C# Console solution with 2 projects. And it doesn't work to. It seems like there is 2 windows for a 1s (CMD-s) for each project. Next seckond window just dissapear and first window is replaced with Console Titled "Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console". So there is the same problem, but why?

Comment: @MiguelCardoso It seems this is not just C# interfaces problem, but VS at all.

Comment: But in this example project (in C# with console) second project is builded contrary to my solution from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I was searching again, but this time just about 'having multiple debug consoles' and i found out this thread

[Multiple Consoles in a Single Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724901/multiple-consoles-in-a-single-console-application) With B.K. answer.
I think this explains evrything.
You can't have multiple debug consoles unless you will make them by yourself. But of course you can open a few windows in normal (no debug) mode.

Comment: This applies to all visual studio projects, not just angular and asp.net core projects. But this was my first time, when i had such a problem with VS consoles.