# how to copy a file from current folder to another folder in C#

Tags: c#, file, copy

How can I copy test.pdf from current folder to C:exfolder 
I know the siple copy way in C# But I want the code which works for any folders which the exe file in in it .
I was confuised beacuse when I wanted to use current folder path visual studio 2008 erros 
beacaus I used :

```
string fileName = "test_log.LDF";
            string sourcePath = @ + Application.StartupPath;
            string targetPath = @"C:\honar2";

            // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
            // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

Comment: `Plzsendtehcodez` is not a valid question here on StackOverflow. Please try to make your questions better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get directory for the exe file using the `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`, then use the `System.IO.File.Copy` method to copy that file to any destination. Also for getting the current directory you may want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path/15653950#15653950)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    string fileName = "test.txt";
    string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder";
    string targetPath =  @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\SubDir";

    // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

For more information Please follow [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc148994(v=vs.100).aspx)