# Selenium driver location search path

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, ncrunch

I'm trying to set up selenium tests in nCrunch which outputs the tests to its own temp folder.

I'm getting the following error when I create the driver (`new PhantomJSDriver()`):

> OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException : The PhantomJS.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable.

However I have checked and `PhantomJS.exe` does exist in the current directory (\bin\debug).

I then tried using `new PhantomJSDriver(".\\")` which should be the current directory and that does work.

What is the *"current directory"* Selenium is referring to in this message?

Comment: A very useful tool for this type of scenario is Microsoft's process explorer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx   Set a breakpoint just before the new(), turn on process explorer, and step over the error.  Process Explorer will show where in the filesystem it looked

Comment: You can look into the source code to determine the search path logic.

Comment: @Luke McGregor Please check the following post, it's in JAVA however might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273403/how-to-enable-phantomjs-webdriver-in-selenium/42275761#42275761

Answer (score 1):

Rather than assuming `".\\"`, get the current working working directory by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` or `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` . Take a look at [Get current folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path).

Answer (score 1):

*new PhantomJSDriver()* will use your *bin* folder

if *PhantomJS.exe* does not exist there, try to find where it's located and insert full path in constructor

```
new PhantomJSDriver("real_path_to_PhantomJS.exe")
```