# How to enable PhantomJS WebDriver in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I need to rewrite my Java program from ChromeDriver to PhantomJS. I think i should just enable PhantomJS instead of ChromeDriver and nothing more (am i right?). I tried a few ways to do this, but i always get NoClassDefFoundError.

My way of enabling ChromeDriver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", CHROMEDRIVER_PATH);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And this is how i tried to enable PhantomJS:

```
 DesiredCapabilities DesireCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
 DesireCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, PHANTOMJSDRIVER_PATH);
 WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(DesireCaps);
```

Second try

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, PHANTOMJSDRIVER_PATH);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

Third

```
File src = new File(PHANTOMJSDRIVER_PATH);
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used as below in my project and it works.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path","path/to/phantomjsdriver");
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

Also, make sure you have phantomjs dependency in your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had detro dependency 1.2.0 in my pom. Now it works!