# SendKeys to a windows file dialog

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, dialog, sendkeys

I want to send the string `ABC` to the input field of a windows file dialog. With this code line I can set the focus to the correct element. I see a blinken cursor.

```
var filedialogOverlay = drv.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
```

But the following code doesn't write the string into the element.

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
filedialogOverlay.SendKeys("ABC");
```

EDIT:
The file upload prompt is shown by a website which I want to test. Because of black box testing I can't see the source code. Is there a tool to analyse the GUI?

When I right click the input element I get the following choices.

[image]

Comment: If you mean File Upload Prompt like http://www.cumc.columbia.edu/it/howto/remote/img/dnuploadfile25.jpg, your code will not work. `drv.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();` allows to switch to element which you currently focused on, e.g. text input field with cursor inside... To upload file you need to send path to file to `<input type="file">` element

Comment: The method `ActiveElement()` returns the active element in the page and not the file dialog. Selenium doesn't support the file dialog but it supports file upload by calling `Sendkeys` directly on the `<input type="file">` element  with the path of the file.

Comment: @Florent B. Could you show me the full code in an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SendKeys.SendWait of Windows Form

```
//Input the file path into the filename field:
SendKeys.SendWait(longfilepath);
//Input "Enter" key
SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry for late reply, you can refer to this link : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to upload file, try to send path to file directly to appropriate input field:

```
drv.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']")).SendKeys("ABC");
```

P.S. If there are more than one input fields for file upload located on page, you might need more specific `XPath`, like `"//input[@id='some_specific_file_upload']"`...

Comment: But how do I get the input field name? I mean the standard dialog overlay from "Windows".

Comment: To open file upload prompt you, obviously, need to click on button, right? Check `HTML` of that button and you should find mentioned `<input type="file">` element

Comment: I have no chance to see the code. I am a black box tester. Is there a tool for analysing the GUI?

Comment: You can check `HTML` simply with your browser. Use right click on required web-element and select something like `inspect element`

Comment: Do not left click on Upload button to open File Upload Dialog. Right click on Upload button which is located on page