# How can I get the filepath of the current open folder?

Tags: c#, directory, filepath

I want to be able to have the current open filepath name read and then display the options of filtered extentions. So for example if the currently open folder is say c:\Thisfolder and it has .jpgs and .txt files in it I want to be able to list a single .txt file in a selection area to choose from as the default file. I have tried to use DirectoryInfo and Folder Browser Dialog but no joy at the moment.

Many thanks

I will be sending my clients a folder with jpgs and a single file with an .syvw extention. What I want is for the program to read the .syvw file and show it as an option to open it. In the same way a folder will open showing the contents of a USB or disc once it is inserted into the computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current folder path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path)

Comment: What do you mean by currently open folder?

Answer (score 0):

Tried:

Using System.IO;
..

String currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

?

Comment: that gives me the current directory of the .exe file of the program. What I need is the filepath of the directory or folder when say a USB is inserted into the computer. The computer shows the USB as an open folder, it is that filepath I need to be be able to access.

Comment: Well, probably a way would be possible if you monitor active processes using `System.Diagnostics.Process` namespace and do something once you detect new instance of "Explorer.exe".
Check out [GetProcessesByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname(v=vs.100).aspx).