# Is there a way to find application is starting from desktop shortcut or not in win form?

Tags: winforms, winforms-interop, windowsformsintegration

I am new in winform application.
this there a way to find application is open from desktop shortcut icon.

Comment: Add a command line to the shortcut, if its there at runtime it was launched from a shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put an argument in the shortcut:

[image]

and check for it in your application via its `Environment.CommandLine`:

[image]

But other than that, no.  You won't be able to tell whether someone directly clicked on the executable or even if someone deleted the argument in the shortcut.

Comment: Thank you and is there a way to get Start In path?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: @rony:You can find correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path