# C# could not find file 'filepath'

Tags: c#

I'm getting the 'cannot be found' error although the file does exist and the path is right. I have tried AudiosInfo.txt.txt and it does not work.

```
FileStream f = new FileStream("AudiosInfo.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader s = new StreamReader(f);
string l=s.ReadLine();
MessageBox.Show(l);
```

Comment: Try to figure out where the current directory is

Comment: how is that ???

Comment: Next time ask Google. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15653921/974045

Comment: Next time don't answer till u understand the question

Comment: Don't use current directory nor relative file paths, pass the full path to `new FileStream` every time.

Comment: You mention that *"the path is right"*, yet there is no path shown, only a file name. You should pass the full path and file name to the `FileStream`.

Comment: Also, most file operations have been wrapped up nicely in the `File` class. You can just do `MessageBox.Show(File.ReadLines(filePath).FirstOrDefault());` to display the first line of the file located at `filePath`

Answer (score 1):

When you are using,

```
FileStream f = new FileStream("AudiosInfo.txt", FileMode.Open);
```

you have to ensure that, `AudiosInfo.txt` file must be stored in your solution's `\bin\Debug` folder.

Otherwise you have to give the full path.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can find the full path: right click on the AudiosInfo.txt file, click on `properties`, click on the `details` tab and take a look at the `folder path`.

Comment: Actually what is the error? That the txt.file cannot be found? Can you please update the codes with the full path?

Answer (score -1):

Might need to use to find the the path

```
string filePath = @"C:\MyDir\MySubDir\myfile.ext";
string directoryName;
int i = 0;

while (filePath != null)
{
    directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
    Console.WriteLine("GetDirectoryName('{0}') returns '{1}'",
        filePath, directoryName);
    filePath = directoryName;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        filePath = directoryName + @"\";  // this will preserve the previous path
    }
    i++;
}
/*
```