# ASP.NET Core 2.1 application not getting correct appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 applications

1. App
2. ClassLibrary

App references ClassLibrary and both have their own appsettings.json file. My class library app has no startup.cs or program.cs so I have a static class that is supposed to read from the local appsettings.json file like this:

```
static class ConfigurationManager
{
    public static IConfiguration AppSetting { get; }
    static ConfigurationManager()
    {
        AppSetting = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
    }
}
```

This is the appsettings.json in the class library

```
{
  "AccountsAddress": "http://localhost:55260/api/Accounts/"
}
```

The problem starts when my app runs, it calls a method located in class library. However, the appsettings that is called is not the one in class library. Its the one in the app itself. Is there a way to specify that I want to reference the appsettings in the class library instead of the App.

Comment: A class library is a DLL, it's not an executable, it doesn't have a startup location to have an appsettings.json file.

Comment: The problem here is you are calling setbasepath on the current working directory with `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` so when you launch the app it reads the one in the app directory. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify that I want to reference the appsettings in the class library instead of the App.

Rename class library's *appsettings.json* file to something unique to that library.

something like `{classlibname}.appsettings.json`

After renaming it, make sure to set it to be copied to output directory.

Also make sure after renaming it that the code is calling the new name

```
//...
.AddJsonFile("classlibname.appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
//...
```