# C# : saving screenshot into a sub directory within the app base directory?

Tags: c#, directory, screenshot

I am attempting to save a screenshot into the `img` sub-directory located inside of the apps base directory; however, the image file is saved within the apps base directory. What should I do to save the image into the `img` sub-directory?

Code:

```
private void screenCapture()
{
    try
    {
        string appDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDir, "img");

        Bitmap memoryImage;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(1000, 900);
        Size s = new Size(memoryImage.Width, memoryImage.Height);

        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);

        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);

        string fileName =
            string.Format(pathString
            + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss")
            + ".png");

        // save it  
        memoryImage.Save(fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to: System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath); Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path

Comment: You're appending the date string to the end of the path _making `img` part of the file name_. You need to use something like `string fileName = Path.Combine(pathString, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + ".png");`. Or just get rid of `pathString` and directy use `Path.Combine(appDir, "img", DateTime.Now....)`.

Comment: If your `img` directory doesn't exist, you might want to create if first before saving, also, you should do `fileName = Path.Combine(pathString, $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss")}.png");`, sins your first `Path.Combine` would return `pathString` with no leading backslash in which case you would just be saving it to a file named `img{DateTime.Now}.png` in the base directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just not combining the path components and the filename properly. Try this:

```
string appDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDir, "img");
string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + ".png";
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, fileName);
```