# How do I get the installed directory?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm looking to create a console application in C# that can be added to the system path. So of course it will need to operate within the working directory. But I will have public key files installed in the same directory as the executable, so I will need to get the installed directory as well. How can I do this?

**Clarification:**
In a C# console application, I want to be able to access both the working directory and the directory where the EXE file is. *These are different directories.* I know how to get the former, I need to know how to get the latter.

Comment: Application.ExecutablePath from here is probably what you're after. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path)

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to get the directory where your .exe and .dll files are supposed to be (usually the directory that contains your .exe file)**This is probably what you need.**
- `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to get the path that the system shell runs your program in.
- `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().CodeBase` or `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` to get the exact path to your .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

So this works: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`